# SmtpClient in C# failed with 421 Timeout error in SMTP server

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2012

I have a C# client using SmtpClient class to send a email, which normally works well.

But,it does not send email in certain condition.

The client side didn't throw exception at all. It just looks ok. But, the SMTP log showed as below.

250-AUTH LOGIN
250 Ok
04:31:35 PM - Client: MAIL FROM:
04:31:35 PM - Server: 250 Ok
04:31:35 PM - Client: RCPT TO:
04:31:35 PM - Server: 250 Ok
04:31:35 PM - Client: RSET
04:31:35 PM - Server: 250 Ok
04:32:35 PM - Server: 421 Timeout waiting for data from client.

contidions. 
1. It worked when debugging in VS2012
2. It failed whend running it as windwos service in local machine.

This is the only difference I can find between success and failure case. The code used was

```
    public void SendEmail(MailAddressCollection toAddresses, string fromAddress, string subject, string body)
    {
        string smtpHost = emailHost;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpHost);
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(emailAccountId, emailAccountPassword);

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        foreach (var toAddress in toAddresses)
        {
            message.To.Add(toAddress);
        }
        message.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = body;
        message.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;

        smtp.Send(message);
    }
```

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779856/cannot-send-smtp-email-from-windows-service-on-win7

Comment: David, Thanks for the comment. It's similar, but there are a few differences. The SMTP server in my case hosted in the same local machine. (fake SMTP java version). and I haven't seen any exception on the client side.

Comment: Addition: This works fine in windows 2008 server.